# Handling multiple users concurrently in AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm developing a SAAS based application where the users are given access to aws resources via web identity federation (Cognito). Currently I retrieve the credentials from cognito and reconfigure the sdk in auth call.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");


AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                        IdentityPoolId : 'pool-id',
                        Logins : {
                            'cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx' : cognitoUser.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
                        }
                    });
```

When ever an authenticated user makes an api call I reconfigure the node aws sdk with that users credentials, and make the subsequent aws api call. But how to handle this workflow when two users are concurrently making an api call. Is there a way in aws sdk mitigate this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found any solution? We are likely running into the same problem...